# Dynamic Component Generation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have an ordered list of components I'd like to render. However, I'd like to be able to easily add and remove components from this list, so I don't want to hard code these components.  I've built a solution that "works", but Typescript is unhappy with me. I'm looking for a way to tell Typescript that what I'm doing is okay.

Setup:

```js
// workflowLogic.ts

type WorkflowForm<T, P> = {
  identifier: string
  populateProps: (arg: T) => P
  component: (props: P) => JSX.Element | null
} & (StepOne<T> | StepTwo<T>)

type StepOne<T> = {
  identifier: 'step1'
  populateProps: (arg: T) => StepOneProps
}

type StepTwo<T> = {
  identifier: 'step2'
  populateProps: (arg: T) => StepTwoProps
}

const step1: WorkflowForm<SomeInputType, StepOneProps> = {
  identifier: 'step1',
  populateProps: (arg: SomeInputType) => ({
    age: arg.age
  }),
  component: StepOneComponent
}

const step2: WorkflowForm<SomeInputType, StepTwoProps> = {
  identifier: 'step2',
  populateProps: (arg: SomeInputType) => ({
    name: arg.name
  }),
  component: StepTwoComponent
}
export const workflow = { step1, step2 }
```

```js
// Implementation

import { workflow } from './workflowLogic'

function WorkflowComponent() {
  const { currentStepIdentifier } = useContext(WorkflowContext) // 'step1' | 'step2'
  const workflowInput: SomeInputType = useGetWorkflowInput()
  
  const currentStep = workflow[currentStepIdentifier]

  const props = currentStep.populateProps(workflowInput)

  return (
    {currentStep.component(props)} // This is where Typescript is unhappy.
  )
}
```

The message Typescript gives me here is: `Argument of type 'StepOneProps | StepTwoProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StepOneComponent & StepTwoComponent'.`

I understand why it's complaining, but I don't know how to tell typescript that this is not an error.

I have confirmed that the code works as expected. I am able to get the props for each component and render successfully. I just can't get around Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assert the type of currentStep.component(props) to be JSX.Element | null:

**Potential Fix:**

```
function WorkflowComponent() {
  const { currentStepIdentifier } = useContext(WorkflowContext); // 'step1' | 'step2'
  const workflowInput: SomeInputType = useGetWorkflowInput();
  
  const currentStep = workflow[currentStepIdentifier];

  const props = currentStep.populateProps(workflowInput);

  return (
    currentStep.component(props) as JSX.Element | null // Type assertion
  );
}
```

By using the `JSX.Element | null` assertion, you are telling TypeScript that you are confident `currentStep.component(props)` will return either a valid JSX element or null, which aligns with the return type of your component functions.

Comment: yea, I thought about that. I was hoping to find a way that didn't involve asserting that I'm right.